# Create a new column in pandas that is based on two other columns of bools

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df that has two columns consisting of bools.

```
df['trial']
df['subscribe']
```

I want to create a new column `df['without_trial']` that is true when `df['subscribe']` is true and `df['trial']` is false, and false otherwise.

How can I do that? I have tried with the `df.loc` but it never gives me the right values.

Answer (score 2):

If you have pure boolean columns as input, use the AND (`&`) and NOT (`~`) operators:

```
df['without_trial'] = df['trial'] & ~df['subscribe']
```

If you potentially have mixed values use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (equal) and [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) (not equal):

```
df['without_trial'] = (df['trial'].eq(True)
                     & df['subscribe'].ne(True)
                      )
```